# use absolute value when dividing negative number

Tags: switch-statement, netsuite, saved-searches

I have a transaction saved search in which I have multiple formula columns to display quantities grouped by items when transaction types are Cash Sale and (Cash refund or Credit Memo). I'm now trying to add another formula column to divide returned quantities by sales quantities by using the below formula, but receiving an error "ERROR: Possible Divide by Zero" I believe the issue is that NetSuite referencing (-) negative returned quantities, and I need to figure out how to have it calculate this formula by using absolute value without the (-) negative. I've tried to sue the Saved Search absolute value function, but then the whole search errors out. Is this possible through case statement expression?

Formula:
Case when {type} = 'Cash Refund' or {type} = 'Credit Memo' THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END/(Case when {type} = 'Cash Sale' or {type} = 'Invoice' THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END)

Comment: Please share the formula used to divide returned quantities by sales quantities.

Comment: For `return_qty / sales_qty` any period where there are returns without sales you will have a divide by 0.

Answer (score 1):

You can generally avoid divide by zero issues if you wrap the divisor in a NULLIF() function:

```
Case when {type} = 'Cash Refund' or {type} = 'Credit Memo' THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END/NULLIF((Case when {type} = 'Cash Sale' or {type} = 'Invoice' THEN {quantity} ELSE 0 END), 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried your formula, but the results are just displaying "0" value. Not sure if NULLIF will work here because (every) returned quantity is stored in NS as negative for example -4, -8, -11. I need to some how remove the negative and have the system calculate using for example  4, 8, 11.

Comment: Negative quantities are not the problem - returns without sales are. `-5/0` and `5/0` will both produce a divide by zero error.

Comment: You can use `ABS({quantity})` instead of just `{quantity}` for the return quantities, but the bigger issue may be what criteria you're using and how you're grouping the results.  The formula as shown (adapted from yours) will only return a single result at a time, so it would have a dividend or a divisor, but not both.  You could wrap both sides of the division in a `SUM()` and set the "Summary" field to Minimum if you're grouping the results.  Best to show your Criteria and Results tabs so we can help without guessing so much.

Answer (score 0):

Use ABS() to convert negative values to positive.

ABS(-4) returns 4.

Try this, ABS(return_qty) / ABS(sales_qty)

And use Nullif( , ) to avoid divide by ZERO error.